# How to get $post_id to default to current post

Tags: wordpress, post, comments, default

I am using Wordpress, and on my single post page I wan't to display all the comments to this particular post, but I get all comments to all posts on my blog. Shouldn't $post_id default to the post in question? I have this code:

```
$comments = get_comments();
foreach($comments as $comment) :

  if ($comment->comment_approved == 1) {

    echo '<hr /><h5>' . $comment->comment_author . '
    </h5><p class="visitorAuthor">' . $comment->comment_date . '</p>
    <p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
    if ($comment->comment_author_url != '') { echo '<p><a href="' . $comment->comment_author_url . '" Target="_blank">Besök min hemsida</a>' ; }

 }

endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using `<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>` in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) Then You dont have to pass post_id this will automatically display comments of the particular post. [comments_template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template)

but for get_comments, you have to pass **post_id** parameter to get comments for particular post.
by default it will get all the comments [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Example

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'post_id' => 1, // use post_id, not post_ID
);
$comments = get_comments($args);
```

Above code should get all the approved comments for post id 1